# Java make program check if a word is in the dictionary

Tags: java, file, dictionary, boolean

I want this program to check if a word is in the dictionary how would I do this in a format close to this? What should I add to this to make it work? Here is my code:

```
    String file = ("/Users/Brandon/Desktop/code/Good.txt");

    Dictionary dict = new Hashtable();

    boolean checkWord(String s){
        if(StringIsInDictionary) return true;
        return false
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by `if(StringIsInDictionary) return true;` what is StringIsInDictionary ?

Comment: You cannot have method inside a method in Java. Period.

Comment: @PradeepSimha the lines are a little blurred with anonymous classes and lambda expressions.

Comment: Sorry I put the wrong code in one second I'll change it>

Comment: @clcto I think that much of detail is not required seeing the beginning level of OP :)

Comment: You have a (very) few of the bits you need.  For the simplest implementation you'd read your dictionary file, parse it into individual words, insert the words into a hashtable of some sort (probably a Set would be best), then search that hashtable to validate individual words.  (This is going to be a few more lines than you're showing above.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do something like this (just an outline) -

- Read and parse the text file that contains the dictionary data
- Put the dictionary words into a data structure. You can use `HashSet` which is a kind of a `Set`.
- Check if that set contains the word that you want to check.

Now, writing the actual code is left to you, you can use Javadocs to find out what methods you need to use.